# Flow uncovered code warning when exporting react redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to export a component with the react redux `connect` function like so:

```
//@flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

type Props = {
    children?: any,
    someInfo: string
}

class ToDo extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        let { someInfo } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="todo-page">
                <pre>{ JSON.stringify(someInfo) }</pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

type StateProps = {
  someInfo: string
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateProps) => {
    const { someInfo } = state;
    return { someInfo };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(ToDo);
```

and i'm getting uncovered code warning for the last line (export one).

The error that i'm getting:

[image: flow type error]

---

How should I structure my code and remove this kind of warning?

Comment: Do you have type definition for `react-redux`? Otherwise flow doesn't know the type of `connect` function. You can install it with https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed Also, `children?` could be `React.Node` type as shown in https://flow.org/en/docs/react/children/

Comment: I've installed flow typed but still get the warning. Should i import it in the file somehow?

Comment: Please post either the specific error, or the full code so we can help you?!

Comment: There is nothing more actually besides the render method in the class which only shows the info from the state (redux). Just in case i'll add more details though.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, it was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I have this on my projects as well, but I uncheck/unselect the flow coverage option at the bottom of VSCode.  This will toggle between flow errors in your code and uncovered code.

[image]

Uncovered code is external code (imported modules), sometimes your own, more likely 3rd party dependencies (as in this instance) that do not define flow types. As a result flow is unable to check types for consistency.

You could install the `react-redux` type definitions from `flow-typed` as suggested in the comments. Actually I tried this in the past and lead to a whole world of pain, so I left it.

As a side note, consider this... aiming for 100% type checking coverage is as harmful as aiming for 100% test coverage (google it). Aim for a high, realistically achievable coverage and don't waste time chasing the last few percent.